# Software to magnify an application

Tags: windows-7, accessibility

My company is using a few old apps that do not scale well when used with high resolution screens. The GUI elements appear very small, making the users angry. As all those apps are bound to be decommissioned sooner or later, we won't spend energy on those.

I know Windows 10 offer a means to deal with this problem, but we're still on Windows 7. Migration to Windows 10 won't be complete until late 2018.

So I'm looking for an app to magnify an application (not the whole screen or just a zone under the mouse pointer). It should work per app, not per window, meaning any pop-up window created by the app should be magnified too.

So far I have tested [WindowWatcher](http://www.airesoft.co.uk/windowwatcher) and [OnTopReplica](https://ontopreplica.codeplex.com/), which are close to what I'd like, but do not work well with pop-up windows.